# Image of ring morphism is a subfield

Tags: ring-theory, finite-fields

Let $\Bbb F$ a finite field and $\varphi$ the map defined by

$$\varphi: \Bbb Z\to \Bbb F,\; n\mapsto n\cdot 1_{\Bbb F}$$
I want to prove that $Im \varphi$ is a subfield of $\Bbb F$. So far I proved that $\varphi$ is a ring morphism so $Im \varphi$ is a subring. What I need to prove now is that all element of $Im \varphi\setminus\{0_{\Bbb F}\}$ are invertible and I'm stuck on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Another proof:*

There's a very simple reason for this: $\operatorname{Im f}$ is a subring of the finite field $F$, hence is an integral domain. So it results from the following result:

> A finite integral domain is a field.

Indeed, if $A$ is this domain, for any $a\neq 0$ in $A$, the map $\;\begin{aligned}[t]m_a\colon A&\longrightarrow A\\x&\longmapsto ax\end{aligned}\;$ is injective since $A$ is an  integral domain. Now on a finite set, injective means surjective, so $1$ is attained, i.e. there exists $x\in A$ such that $ax=1$: this proves any non-zero $a$ is invertible.

Answer (score 2):

If $R\to \mathbb F$ is *any* nonzero ring homomorphism, then $Im(f)$ is obviously a domain, and of course finite domains are fields.

This is easy to see, and contained in many questions on the site. For a nonzero element $a$, you can consider the powers $a^n$. This can't be infinte, so there exists $n, m$ integers such that $a^n=a^m$. Cancelling away the smaller power, you get a power of $a$ equal to $1$. So in fact, $a^{-1}$ is a power of $a$, and that's in the image too, of course.

---

Now that I actually go back and see how you're defining the map from $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb F$, I see other possiblities too. The fact that the codomain of the map is an integral domain implies that $\ker(f)=(p)$ for some prime $p$ or $\{0\}$, but the latter case is ruled out since the codomain is finite. By the first isomorphism theorem, $Im(f)\cong \mathbb Z/(p)$.

Comment: I can't use Wedderburn's little theorem. Is there a elementary method?

Comment: I don't understand the proof on wiki. Let $R = \varphi(\mathbb{Z})$ a finite integral domain and $K = \text{Frac}(R)$ (here $K \subset \mathbb{F}$). If $a \in R, a \ne 0$ then $a^n = a^m$ for some $n > m $, thus $a^{n-m} = 1$ and $a^{-1} = a^{n-m-1}$ in $K$ and hence $a^{-1} = a^{m-n-1}$ in $R$.

Comment: @user66407 I was just thinking along the same lines, and determined a more elementary method.

Comment: +1.  Since $\mathbb{F}$ is finite its characteristic is some prime $p$.  By your definition of $\varphi$, it must have kernel $(p)$ as @rschwieb pointed out.

Comment: @reuns What's your question? What you said just says that for each $a\in Im(f)$, $a^{-1}=a^k\in Im(f)$ for some natural number $k$.

Comment: So it is a field. My question was why the proof on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem#Proof) is complicated, and I got it : domain doesn't mean commutative ring. So clearly it is much more complicated than the commutative case (for which $\text{Frac}(R)$ is a field)

Comment: @reuns Well, what you're saying is true: domain *typically* means commutative domain. And yeah, I don't know for sure why they brought $Frac(R)$ into it. It seems unnecessary. Whcih wiki specifically are you looking at?